# Disconnect pyqt signal from connected function

Tags: python, pyqt5

I've connected a returnPressed signal of QLineEdit to a function but i don't know how to disconnect it from the connected one.

`self.usernameLineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.send_code_clicked)`

I would be pleased if you can help me.
Thanks

I've tried to disconnect with the following codes but it didn't work

`self.confirmationCodeLineEdit.returnPressed.disconnect()`
`self.confirmationCodeLineEdit.returnPressed.disconnect(self.send_code_clicked)`

Comment: `self.confirmationCodeLineEdit.returnPressed.disconnect(self.send_code_clicked)` should work. Please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Andrey No, it should not (at least based on the provided code), since the connection was done on a different object (`usernameLineEdit`, not `confirmationCodeLineEdit`). A slot-specific disconnection can only be done when all these aspects match: the emitting object, the signal and the target slot/function used in the connection. Furthermore, if the connection was done on an overloaded signal, the signature must also be matched.

Comment: @musicamante, thanks for pointing out that OP called disconnect on different objects. Seems like this was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disconnect a signal from a function in PyQt, you need to use the `disconnect` signal's method of the same object it was connected to.

```py
self.usernameLineEdit.returnPressed.disconnect(self.send_code_clicked)
```